# Component part shown in joomla frontend

Tags: joomla, components

How do I display the form in the frontend in Joomla 2.5, just like the Create Article form shown in the frontend?

Comment: create an HTML form in your article or use some extension for form

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously create an form in an article but it will be pointless as the form will require PHP functions which cannot be written in an article.

Your best bet would be to develop a simple module which you can embed in an article or download a free form extension from the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback).